# Access 2010 Data Macros Causing Form Refresh For No Reason

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'd like to report this as a bug to Microsoft, but was wondering if anyone else has encountered this.

++++

Here's a really interesting and obscure issue with Access 2010 Data Macros.

The issue is that the firing of a before update data macro on a table is causing a unwanted and unnecessary form refresh.  The  refresh is clearing all the selections from several multi-select listboxes on th form.  I want the selections to stay.  The form worked just as I wanted prior to adding the data macro (no clearing of mslb selections).

To reproduce this issue.

This is happening in a split / front end - back end scenario.  With front and back both being Access 2010 files.

In back end ACCDB...
Create a table "Items" with ID and Description columns and also a date_updated column.
Put a Data Macro on the before update on this table that sets the "date_updated" field to now().

In front end ACCDB... with Items table linked...

Now create a blank form unbound to any table.
Create an unbound multi select listbox on the form and populate via any other table or with a value list (doesn't matter what the rowsource is) and it can be bound or unbound - doesn't matter.

- now notice if you run the form, select some items in the listbox then press F5 ("refresh"), your listbox selections are cleared as expected. this just to demonstrate that refresh of form clears listbox selections. *

Now create a button on the form.  Behind this button, put VBA code like this.

docmd.runsql "insert into Items (Description) values ('test')"     (just any valid sql statement that inserts a row into the items table)

open the form.

select several items in the list box.

press the button.  you will see that the form is refreshed and therefore you lose the listbox selections.

close the form and now remove the data macro from the Items table.

open the form, select items in the listbox, press the button.

Now that there is no data macro, the form is not refreshed and the selections stay.

++++++++++++++++++

Bottom line:  for some reason a data macro firing on a table totally unrelated to the form (but triggered by code behind the form) causes a form refresh.

Disable the data macro and the form does not refresh.

Why would a data macro... on the back end ACCDB file... cause a form refresh on the front end?  Remember, the form has nothing to do with the table, or the data macro.

This is forcing me to abandon my data macros.  I don't think this is intended or desired behavior in Access 2010.

I'd love to get confirmation from anyone that this is an issue!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm your issue when the `Before Change` data macro was in place and the list box `Multi Select` setting was `Extended`. Under the same conditions the list box selections were **not** clobbered if its `Multi Select` setting was `Simple`. (I noticed that when `Multi Select` was set to `Simple` then [F5] would not clear the selections either.)

Comment: Thanks Gord!  I'm going to try to report this to Microsoft.  It's a problem for my design!  Thanks again.